# Problems with "desc" keyword in Rails app gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, capistrano

I'm trying to install a new gem into my working Ruby Rails application. (Dotenv, explained [here](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv/blob/master/README.md) for those interested.) However, each time I try to include it in the app, my deploy crashes with the following error:

```
/Users/nadams/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@orbit/gems/dotenv-0.8.0/lib/dotenv/tasks.rb:1:
    in `<top (required)>: undefined method `desc' for main:Object (NoMethodError)
```

QUESTION PROPER: Where does the "desc" keyword come from?

(I think the problem is that the "desc" method is added by capistrano, and for some reason Dotenv is being loaded before Capistrano is. But I don't know enough about this to be sure.)

Here is my deploy file:

```
require "bundler/capistrano"
require "capistrano/ext/multistage"
require "rvm/capistrano"

load "config/recipes/base"
load "config/recipes/nginx"
load "config/recipes/unicorn"
load "config/recipes/git"
load "config/recipes/mysql"
load "config/recipes/shared"
load "config/recipes/check"

# Sets up dotenv...
require "dotenv"
require "dotenv/tasks"
require "dotenv/capistrano"
Dotenv.load
# ...done

set :application, "orbit-server"
set :user, "deploy"
set :bundle_cmd, "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global/bin/bundle"
set :default_stage, "testing"
set :deploy_to, "/home/deploy/rails_apps/orbit-server"
set :deploy_via, :remote_cache
set :rvm_ruby_string, "ruby-2.0.0-p0@orbit"
set :rvm_type, :system
set :stages, %w( production staging testing )
set :use_sudo, false

# TODO Remove this code when I get Dotenv working
puts "Deploy branch: "+(ENV["DEPLOY_BRANCH"].nil? ? "nil" :ENV["DEPLOY_BRANCH"])
ENV["DEPLOY_BRANCH"]="release-notes"

set :scm, "git"
set :repository, "git@github.com:[my/repo].git"
set :branch, ENV["DEPLOY_BRANCH"].nil? ? "master" : ENV["DEPLOY_BRANCH"]

default_run_options[:pty] = true
ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true

after "deploy", "deploy:cleanup"
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`desc` is a rake method. you can either `require 'rake'`, or remove:

remove:

```
require "dotenv/tasks"
```

There doesn't appear to be any reason to do that.

Comment: Thanks! I'm pretty sure "require rake" fixed the problem because it got rid of the error I mentioned (giving way to a few other bugs)

Comment: Requiring "dotenv/tasks" ensures that the dotenv environment variables are loaded. I too had to `require "rake"` but only when running my tests within autotest.